# Python: Pyodbc execute stored procedure with parameters

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc

I'm having trouble executing a SQL Server stored procedure with Python 3.4. I'm importing Pyodbc to create the connection and have a few lines that are supposed to sent data to a stored procedure.

My Python:

```
sql = "exec <stored_procedure_name> @int1=?, @int2=?, @string1=?, @int3=?"
params = (irow[0], irow[15], irow[2], irow[6])
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

Stored Procedure:

```
  @int1 int,
  @int2 int,
  @string1 varchar(10),
  @int3 int
AS
BEGIN
  --Do stuff
END
```

I'm not getting an errors in Command Prompt when I execute the script. When I print

```
print(sql, params)
```

I get a weird looking result. Nothing is inserted into the table that is being targeted in the stored procedure.

```
exec <stored_procedure_name> @int1=?, @int2=?, @string1=?, @int3=? (0, 0, 'string', 0)
```

I'm new to Python so any insight would be greatly appreciated. Nothing I've seen on SO has helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the problem was caused by not having autocommit turned on. Pyodbc has autocommit set to False by default.

To enable autocommit, you can declare the connection like:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver="<driver>", server="<server>", database="<database>", uid="<username>", pwd="<password>", autocommit=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think what's missing is the commit. Either run the commit method against the cursor:

```
cursor.execute(sql, params)
cursor.commit()
```

or set `autocommit=True` when the connection is created as in the other answers offered. That connection is used to create the cursor, so the autocommit behavior is inherent to it when the `execute()` is called:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver="<driver>", server="<server>", 
                      database="<database>", uid="<username>", pwd="<password>", 
                      autocommit=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Params are usually passed as a tuple, so

```
params = (irow[0], irow[15], irow[2], irow[6])
```

should work

Comment: Thank you for the response. That didn't work. I updated the question to include the parenthesis and a piece of my stored procedure.